# Is there a way to filter Windows Event Logs by user?

Tags: windows-10, event-log, event-viewer

I have my kid using my computer with a separate account and I would like to see all the events triggered by his user account. Is there a way to do this either with the Event Viewer or Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 has a sophisticated mechanism for monitoring your kid,
and if necessary restrict his computer and internet activities.

This is called Microsoft Family Safety and you can learn more about it in:

- [Microsoft Family Safety](https://account.microsoft.com/family/about?lang=en-gb&ru=https:%2F%2Faccount.microsoft.com%2Ffamily%3Flang%3Den-gb)
- [What is a Microsoft family group?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/what-is-a-microsoft-family-group-b6280c9d-38d7-82ff-0e4f-a6cb7e659344)
- [Manage Your Kid’s Screen Time and Track Online Activity in Windows 10](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/manage-kids-screen-time-track-online-activity-windows-10/)

Comment: "Is there a way to do this either with the Event Viewer or Powershell?" How does your answer address the question?

Comment: @DavidPostill: I assume the Event Viewer or Powershell are not mandatory. His basic wish is "I would like to see all the events triggered by his user account", which this does answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately Microsoft Family Safety is not as sophisticated as it seems, which is why I'm looking for a way to see the actual events. MFS makes some assumptions about the events which do not seem right and I would like to verify those myself.